# Remaining part calculations with modulus "%" and bitwise and "&" causes different results on AVX2

Tags: c, operators, intel, logical-operators, avx2

I am trying to convert float values to integer values by using Intel intrinsincs for AVX2. My simple code is as follows:

```
void convert_f2i(float *fin, int *iout, int iLen)
{
    int i, index, iDiv8, iLeft;
    int *iin1;  
    __m256 v0;
    __m256i vi0;
    iDiv8 = iLen/8;

    for(i=0; i<iDiv8; i++) 
    {
        v0 = _mm256_load_ps(fin+i*8);   
        vi0 = _mm256_cvttps_epi32(v0);          
        _mm256_store_si256((__m256i *)(iout+i*8),  vi0);
    }
    iLeft = iLen%8;
/*  iLeft = iLen&7;*/
    if (iLeft)
    {        
        v0  = _mm256_load_ps(fin+i*8);
        vi0 = _mm256_cvttps_epi32(v0);  
        iin1 = (int *)&vi0;
        for(i=0; i<iLeft; i++)             
        {    
            index = iLen-iLeft+i;  
            printf("iLeft:%d i:%d %d  %d index:%d\n", iLeft, i, iin1[i], ((int *)&vi0)[i], index);
            iout[index] = iin1[i];
        }                                   
    }
}
```

I am running the code for iLen = 28671. The first 28664 results are correct. But the last 7 results are problemetic.
If I compile the code with the "iLeft = iLen%8" line open, I get the following result:
    `/*compiled with iLeft = iLen%8 */
    iLeft:7 i:0 9  9 index:28664
    iLeft:7 i:1 4  4 index:28665
    iLeft:7 i:2 9  9 index:28666
    iLeft:7 i:3 6  6 index:28667
    iLeft:7 i:4 4  4 index:28668
    iLeft:7 i:5 2  2 index:28669
    iLeft:7 i:6 1  1 index:28670`which is correct.

On the other hand, if I compile the code with the "iLeft = iLen&7" line open, I get the following result:`/*compiled with iLeft = iLen&7 */
    iLeft:7 i:0 3  3 index:28664
    iLeft:7 i:1 6  6 index:28665
    iLeft:7 i:2 3  3 index:28666
    iLeft:7 i:3 8  8 index:28667
    iLeft:7 i:4 0  0 index:28668
    iLeft:7 i:5 3  3 index:28669
    iLeft:7 i:6 5  5 index:28670` which is not correct.

9-4-9-6-4-2-1 are the expected results and 3-6-3-8-0-3-5 are the results of indexes between 28656-28662. I don't understand what is changing when I calculate iLeft differently. In both ways iLeft=7, yet the results are not the same.

Can someone tell me what might be the issue?

Comment: Do you mind creating a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? The readers might not have access to your library calls and they are probably not essential for the question.

Comment: It is highly unlikely the cause is due to the different calculation of iLeft, as iLeft is the same in both ways. It is more likely there is a problem somewhere else and, for whatever reason, the compiler/linker made a different memory layout with one calculation than with the other (possibly different count of instructions). I suggest you try it with an array of16 and one with 7 floats and see the results. Then check your other codes. And make sure the Intel alignment requirements have been met!

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Note that `iLeft = iLen%8` is not the same as `iLeft = iLen&7` when `iLen < 0`.  The compiler cannot assume `iLen` is positive given the signature `convert_f2i(float *fin, int *iout, int iLen)`.

Comment: @Chux, can we assume positive array sizes? Even with different code, the outcomes will then be the same and so the code following it will perform the same. Then the error must be elsewhere. Different code= different code size= posibility of locating elsewhere in memory= exposure of UB of another location?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie  I see assuming positive`iLen` limits potential solutions to this post.  OP is having a problem and has not posted a MCVE (and have voted accordingly)  - the unposted calling code may be calling `convert_f2i()` with unexpected parameters.

Comment: @Lundin 
I am spawning the following function:
void convert (void){
 int iLen = 28*1024;

 fin1R = memalign(32, iLen*sizeof(float));
 ioutR = memalign(32, iLen*sizeof(int));
 
 ReadFile("In/fpData2.bin",  iLen*sizeof(float), fin1R);

 convert_f2i(fin1R, ioutR, iLen-1);  
}
ReadFile is another function that I use to fill the fin1R with random numbers.

Comment: @Chux I run the code for only positive integer numbers.

Comment: @iaksoy Perhaps code only uses  positive integer numbers.  Yet post lacks enough code to demonstrate that assertion - and _something_ is wrong.  Hence the value of  a MCVE

Answer (score 1):

Because `iLeft` has the same value in both cases, the true reason for the differences OP sees must be somewhere else.

Rather than start a blind hunt for the actual cause, I personally would just rewrite the function for simplicity:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <string.h>

void truncate_floats_to_ints(int *dst, const float *src, size_t count)
{
    const size_t  nvecs = count / 8;
    const size_t  nfloats = count & 7;
    const float  *end = src + 8 * nvecs;

    while (src < end) {
        const __m256   fvec = _mm256_load_ps(src);
        const __m256i  ivec = _mm256_cvttps_epi32(fvec);
        _mm256_store_si256((__m256i *)dst, ivec);
        src += 8;
        dst += 8;
    }

    if (nfloats) {
        __v8sf  fvec;
        __v8si  ivec;
        memcpy(&fvec, src, nfloats * 4);
        ivec = (__v8si)_mm256_cvttps_epi32(fvec);
        memcpy(dst, &ivec, nfloats * 4);
    }
}
```

Note that this version will not access past the array, even in the case where `count` is not a multiple of 8. While the unused entries in `fvec` get garbage values (from stack) in such cases, corresponding truncated values in `ivec` are also ignored. If you dislike this, you can initialize `fvec` to zeroes.

Also note that both `src` and `dst` must be aligned to 32 bytes. Standard C `malloc()` does not guarantee such alignment, although some implementations (perhaps Windows?) might. The GNU C library `malloc()` does not, and you should use e.g. C11 `aligned_alloc(32, size)` where `size` is a multiple of 32 to allocate memory for such vector arrays.

If you dislike the `memcpy()`s, you can replace them with your own custom function, for example

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

static inline void vector_copy_part(void *dst, const void *src, const size_t count)
{
    switch (count & 7) {
        case 7: ((uint32_t *)dst)[6] = ((uint32_t *)src)[6];
        case 6: ((uint64_t *)dst)[2] = ((uint64_t *)src)[2];
                ((uint64_t *)dst)[1] = ((uint64_t *)src)[1];
                ((uint64_t *)dst)[0] = ((uint64_t *)src)[0];
                break;
        case 5: ((uint32_t *)dst)[4] = ((uint32_t *)src)[4];
        case 4: ((uint64_t *)dst)[1] = ((uint64_t *)src)[1];
                ((uint64_t *)dst)[0] = ((uint64_t *)src)[0];
                break;
        case 3: ((uint32_t *)dst)[2] = ((uint32_t *)src)[2];
        case 2: ((uint64_t *)dst)[0] = ((uint64_t *)src)[0];
                break;
        case 1: ((uint32_t *)dst)[0] = ((uint32_t *)src)[0];
    }
}

void truncate_floats_to_ints(int *dst, const float *src, size_t count)
{
    const size_t  nvecs = count / 8;
    const size_t  nfloats = count & 7;
    const float  *end = src + 8 * nvecs;

    while (src < end) {
        const __m256   fvec = _mm256_load_ps(src);
        const __m256i  ivec = _mm256_cvttps_epi32(fvec);
        _mm256_store_si256((__m256i *)dst, ivec);
        src += 8;
        dst += 8;
    }

    if (nfloats) {
        __v8sf  fvec;
        __v8si  ivec;
        vector_copy_part(&fvec, src, nfloats);
        ivec = (__v8si)_mm256_cvttps_epi32(fvec);
        vector_copy_part(dst, &ivec, nfloats);
    }
}
```

This code copies the data using 64-bit integer register (native register size on architectures with AVX support) and possibly one 32-bit integer register for the odd element. (OP's code uses a loop to copy 32-bit integers, which is quite okay -- it's harder for the compiler to optimize, but as it is at most 7 integer copies, it's not like it will take any significant time anyway.)

In general, one should avoid copying `float` (or `double`) values in loops, because that always involves the floating-point unit (AVX registers on these architectures), and GCC at least isn't very good at vectorizing such. Copying floating-point data using normal general registers (same-sized integers) on AVX-capable architectures produces the exact same registers, without involving the AVX registers at all.

GCC-5.4 compiles the above code to a simple jump table with eight entries, and simple moves using the `rax` or `eax` register; quite acceptable, overall. The loop in `truncate_floats_to_ints()` is just six instructions (`vcvttps2dq`, `addq`, `vmovdqa`, `addq`, `cmpq`, `ja`).

The above implementations both passed my quick tests, but it is always possible there might lurk an off-by-one bug or such. I don't think so, but if you do find one, do let me know in a comment, so I can fix it.

Comment: I implemented "if (nfloats)..." part to code and it solved the problem. Yet, still I don't understand. Because if I add printf to code as:    
iLeft = iLen&7;
    if (iLeft)
    {        
        v0  = _mm256_load_ps(fin+i*8);
        vi0 = _mm256_cvttps_epi32(v0);  
        iin1 = (int *)&vi0;
        HERE!
 for(i=0; i<iLeft; i++)             
        {    
            index = iLen-iLeft+i;  
            printf("iLeft:%d i:%d %d  %d index:%d\n", iLeft, i, iin1[i], ((int *)&vi0)[i], index);
            iout[index] = iin1[i];}} 
it works.

Comment: So I believe that my problem is related to timing. Somehow, I am assigning results before they are calculated. But I don't understand how I achieve that.
By the way, both my pointers are alligned and I am using GNU-4.8.1.4. I thought that I was copying int values to the loop since they are converted to the int. Yet, am i still using AVX registers?

Comment: @iaksoy: Does your original code produce expected values, if you replace the latter `v0  = _mm256_load_ps(fin+i*8);` with `v0  = _mm256_load_ps(fin+iDiv8*8);`? Note that this instruction will access past the end of the array (because it accesses all 8 elements of the vector) if `iLeft` is nonzero. Your code uses a loop to copy ints (not floats). As I explained, this version is written from scratch, so the comments are general and not directed at your code; I'll reword some of the non-code text to make that clear.